# Where do I put utility functions in my Python project?

Tags: python, function, import, utilities

I need to create a function to rotate a given matrix (list of lists) clockwise, and I need to use it in my `Table` class. Where should I put this utility function (called `rotateMatrixClockwise`) so I can call it easily from within a function in my `Table` class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to make it a member of the `Table` class you could put it into a `utilities` module.

Answer (score 15):

**Make it a static function...**

- add the @staticmethod decorator
- don't include 'self' as the first argument

Your definition would be:

```
@staticmethod
def rotateMatrixClockwise():
    # enter code here...
```

Which will make it callable everywhere you imported 'table' by calling:

```
table.rotateMatrixClockwise()
```

The decorator is only necessary to tell python that no implicit first argument is expected. If you wanted to make method definitions act like C#/Java where self is always implicit you could also use the '@classmethod' decorator.

[Here's the documentation for this coming directly from the python manual.](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#staticmethod)

*Note: I'd recommend using Utility classes only where their code can't be coupled directly to a module because they generally violate the '[Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)' of OOP. It's **almost** always best to tie the functionality of a class as a method/member to the class.*

Comment: "Utility classes violate the SRP" -- to add a bit more detail to that, IMO the point where a utility class gets out of hand is when you have a lot of completely unrelated methods in the same class, then it kind of gets confusing as to whether you should divide up the methods by subject, by use, etc. Though FWIW I've learned to be a bit pragmatic on that, I think I'd rather at first have a slightly more cluttered utility class than a needlessly stateful implementation, and pure functions are usually pretty easy to move to a class if you need to later as things change.